# swift empty dictionary bug? playground vs project

Tags: dictionary, swift, expression

this code work in playground

```
var detaildata:Dictionary=[:]
detaildata = ["apple":"hello"]
detaildata["orange"]="byebye"
```

this code don't work in project

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var detaildata:Dictionary=[:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       detaildata = ["apple":"hello"]
       detaildata["orange"]="byebye"  // Error -> 'Dictionary' is not identical to 'Dictionary<key,Value>'
    }
}
```

do you know why?

I think same code.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't work in my playground, and shouldn't work in yours. When you declare a `Dictionary`, you need to give it both key and value types either explicitly or through type inference. All of these will work:

```
var dict1 = ["apple": "hello"]       // inferred
var dict2: [String: String] = [:]    // explicit
var dict3: Dictionary<String, String> = ["apple": "hello"]  // longest version
```

Neither of these will work:

```
var dict3: Dictionary = [:]          // type inference impossible
var dict4 = [:]                      // same
```

Comment: if I want to add more key/vale
dact1 += ["orange":"byebye"] // error
I don't know hot to do
and one more I want to merge two dictionary
dict4 = dict1+dict2 //error
Can you help me plz?

Comment: You should read Apple's [documentation about dictionaries in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_179) - that should cover all your questions.